# How to add records to a set and print it as json?

Tags: php

I want to add records to a set and then print it as json. Currently I'm trying to add records to an array and unique it:

```
<?php
$res=array();
array_push($res,"a");//add new records
array_push($res,"a");
array_push($res,"b");
print(json_encode($res));//["a","a","b"]
$res=array_unique($res);
print(json_encode($res));//{"0":"a","2":"b"}
```

However, the code creates indexs for data and gives `{"0":"a","2":"b"}` and I except `["a","b"]` as final result. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: See if `array_values()` works-> `print(json_encode(array_values($res)));` I believe it is because the array keys are not sequential so there is an assumption that you want the keys to remain.

Comment: @Rasclatt `array_values()` works. Thanks.